# Affix with scrolling Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

I have a bootstrap modal which sometimes needs to scroll vertically; I want to have a group of DIVs on the right hand side that affix (auto-scroll) as the page scrolls, but using the standard suggestion, nothing much is working.... I have spent all day on this pulling my hair out. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

To make the modal 'scroll', I've done this:

```
.modal {
    /* ... */
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[JS Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/tornadof3/u22k3eqj/1/)
(drag vertical dividers left if necessary so that the GROUP1, GROUP 2 etc are next to the lorem ipsum rather than below...)

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed the same using just a line, **try below**

```
body.modal-open { overflow-y:scroll ; }
```

Comment: Thank you for having a look. I added that CSS to the Fiddle and it didn't work (didn't work on my live project either). Did that work in the fiddle for you?

Comment: can you try this, https://jsfiddle.net/u22k3eqj/9/ is that what you want? or if you know the content then, this one is much better with fix height https://jsfiddle.net/u22k3eqj/10/

Comment: thank you for both of these suggestions; they do change the size of the modal, but don't seem to have any effect on the right hand side divs. I was hoping the 'affix' mechanism would mean that when the user scrolls, those right hand side divs remain in view, like a constant navbar